# Neo4j can be started, but it can't be stopped by regular 'neo4j stop' command

Tags: neo4j, digital-ocean

I am using `DigitalOcean`s' `Ubuntu 16.04` and I am having trouble understanding of why I can successfully start `Neo4j` by typing `sudo neo4j start`, but I can not stop it by `sudo neo4j stop`: it is always writing for me that `neo4j is not running`. I did `ps aux` command and figured out that `neo4j` is run under the name `java`:

[image]

So, I can restart `neo4j` by doing `kill -15 31905`, and then `sudo neo4j start`. Could anyone explain in detail what is going on here? Why `sudo neo4j stop` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, I've looked at the code to do stop, and I can't figure out how it ever worked, at least in 3.X. But then Java isn't my best language. Could I suggest an alternative? Assuming you installed with the Debian Neo4j package, it includes the proper control files to start under systemd. This is [the recommended way to start neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/systemd/). So to start it, use

> sudo systemctl start neo4j

to make sure it restarts after a boot:

> sudo systemctl enable neo4j

to stop:

> sudo systemctl stop neo4j

and finally, to make sure it doesn't restart after a boot,

> sudo systemctl disable neo4j

Should work far better than the neo4j start/stop interface, and give you the advantages of systemd, like being able to examine the standard output, query the current status, etc. This also restarts neo4j if it dies for any reason.